Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Cannot find 'FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin' in scope
Flutter Developers,
I run to this trouble, when i want to run my Flutter project on the IOS (Iphone) Simulator:
Xcode build done.                                           12.7s
Failed to build iOS app
Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Cannot find 'FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin' in scope
/Users/mojamal/Desktop/nesp_application/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift:14:42

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 15 Pro Max.

What I did to fix the error:
1- I did go back to my previous commits, to see if i had made a mistake in the past. (still have that error also there)
2- Did flutter pub upgrade -> flutter pub get -> flutter clean -> flutter build ios -> cd ios -> pod install (Also this sequence of commands didnt work)
But what I also get is:
No valid code signing certificates were found
You can connect to your Apple Developer account by signing in with your Apple ID
in Xcode and create an iOS Development Certificate as well as a Provisioning 
Profile for your project by:
  1- Open the Flutter project's Xcode target with
       open ios/Runner.xcworkspace
  2- Select the 'Runner' project in the navigator then the 'Runner' target
     in the project settings
  3- Make sure a 'Development Team' is selected under Signing & Capabilities > Team. 
     You may need to:
         - Log in with your Apple ID in Xcode first
         - Ensure you have a valid unique Bundle ID
         - Register your device with your Apple Developer Account
         - Let Xcode automatically provision a profile for your app
  4- Build or run your project again
  5- Trust your newly created Development Certificate on your iOS device
     via Settings > General > Device Management > [your new certificate] > Trust

For more information, please visit:
  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/
  AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html

Or run on an iOS simulator without code signing
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
No development certificates available to code sign app for device deployment

But I think this has nothing to do with the problem I'm facing.

You should import the package which includes FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin in AppDelegate.swift.

If you need info before you can phrase a standalone answer according to [answer] please use your commenting privilge to ask a clarification question.
